# Old sci-fi short story about bombs sent back through time and space by aliens to destroy earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

The story I remember and am trying to find: Humans had expanded out into the galaxy. Another race of aliens saw humans making their way towards their sector of space and feared us. That race was not a warring society and didn't have war ships or war strategies in their culture, only a lot of science. So they developed a bomb that could travel through time and space back to Earth millions of years before humans evolved and destroy the planet, therefore eliminating the threat. The bombs, for whatever reason, had to contain a living creature to make course adjustments and time adjustments and to detonate the bomb at the right time. So the aliens genetically engineered a small creature with one arm, one eye, and no legs and placed it into the bomb to do the work. Then they sent dozens of these bombs back through time and space. The story also tells of the journey the bombs took and what happened when they reached our solar system.

The story was part of a sci-fi collection anthology. One of the other stories in the book was called Juggernaut by A. E. van Vogt about an indestructible metal ingot that was put on earth which eventually ended all wars as the metal passed on its properties to any other metal in touched. I recently found this story in a book called A Treasury of Science Fiction, but still no luck finding the alien bombs story.

Comment: [This isfdb page lists all the anthologies that have include Juggernaut](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47567). I was surprised at how few times it has been anthologised. Apart from A Treasury of Science Fiction it has only been collected in The Best of A.E van Vogt and Masterpieces of Science Fiction, but neither look as though they contain the story you describe.

Comment: Yes, I also found this page and researched the contents of each listed anthology which leads me to believe that the webisite doesn't have all the info. It's possible that the short story was published in some obscure sci-fi book. I can only hope that someone else read the same alien bomb story and remmebers the author and/or title.

Comment: I recall one from an anthology, the aliens send a bomb-ship back through time with a pilot, to destroy Earth. It chooses it's target by counting planets in from the outside, and hits the wrong one, causing the asteroid belt. Is that anything familiar? It's a long time ago that I read it - maybe a Heinlein story?

Comment: The story is "T" by Brian Aldiss. It was originally published in a 1956 issue of *Nebula* which you can read here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_4BOUREK-Y34J1Fra3EDaZwgYlabjUlk/view However, it does not seem to have appeared in an anthology with Van Vogt's "Juggernaut", you probably remember that wrong. It did appear in an anthology with Van Vogt's "Black Destroyer".

Comment: YES! This is it, you can defintely mark this thread as solved. I am looking forward to sitting down later tonight with a cuppa tea and reading this story again. I've been looking for this for years. Thank you all.

Comment: Done! Thanks for confirming the duplicate ID. And welcome to sf stack exchange.,